# Are there 5000+ companies with IATA (two-character) codes?

Tags: commercial-aviation, airlines, iata, airline-codes

From [Wikipedia > List of Airlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airlines)

> There are around 5000 airlines with IATA codes.

From [Wikipedia > List of Airlines Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airline_codes)

> IATA airline designators [..] are two-character codes [..]

and

> after an airline is delisted, the code becomes available for reuse after six months

---

The last quotation suggests that no two airline companies can share the same IATA code.

Depending on the characters allowed, a two-character codes can make $26^2=676$ combinations or eventually $36^2=1296$ combinations. It would take at least 71 different characters authorized to register 5000 companies ($71^2=5041$). It is unlikely that 71 or more characters are authorized. It seems paradoxical to me.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: In [this list](https://www.iata.org/about/members/Pages/airline-list.aspx?All=true) from IATA themselves, there are about 260 airlines with a IATA code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's obviously an error in that Wikipedia page. The "5000 airlines with IATA codes" text actually links to:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airline_codes

which lists lots of airlines (over 6000), but most of those have ICAO (3 letter) codes, but not IATA (2 letter) codes.